# Как сделать зависание и перезагрузку windows 10 из батника?

Tags: windows-10, bat

Как написать небольшой батник, который бы перегружал систему и потом бы от перегруза был ребут windows 10.

Дано: чистая система, ничего постороннего ставить нельзя и подключать к интернету. Пробовал через бесконечный запуск paint, но компу все равно (64gb ddr4, 3090, i9 10x...).

Коллеги подсказывают через загруз ядра, но суть в том, что бы батник был просто и кода было бы по минимуму. Как быть?

Comment: Какую задачу вы пытаетесь этим решить?

Comment: @NNL993 - как минимум, развлекательную )))

Answer (score 0):

Нужна форк-бомба?

Запишите эту строку в файл `fb.bat` и запустите его:

```
@for /l %%x in (1,1,2) do @start /min /realtime cmd.exe /C fb.bat
```

Этот файл, будучи запущен, запускает 2 своих копии и выходит.
Напишите что получилось.
Для усиления эффекта можно заменить `cmd.exe /C fb.bat` на `cmd.exe /K fb.bat`

Comment: Причём тут форк-бомба? Она просто заполнит диск компьютера.

Comment: Она не пишет на диск.  Она занимает оперативку.  Всю.